# Banach space with unconditional basis and its subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

I am interseted in the following problem. By Bessaga and Pelczynski paper *On bases and unconditional convergence of series in Banach
spaces* we know that if $X$ is a Banach space with a basis $(x_n)$ and $Y$ is its closed subspace with infinite dimension, then there is $Z$ - subspace of $Y$ with a basis which is equivalent to a block basis of $(x_n)$. I was wondering however about some *modification* and start from space $X$ with *unconditional basis*.

Namely, suppose that $X$ is a Banach space with unconditional basis and let $Y$ be a closed subspace in $X$ of infinite dimension. Is it true that there is $Z$ - subspace of $Y$ that also has an unconditional basis?

Intuition tells me that this statement should be true, although I have realized that in Banach space theory many things turn out to be contrary to what I think.

I will be grateful for any (sketch of) proof (or counterexamples), and for some references if it is not trivial.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I have edited my post. I hope it is ok now.

Comment: If you apply the theorem from Bessaga, Pełczyński paper there is a subspace $Z$ to a block basis of $(x_n)$ Perhaps this block basis is unconditional if the original one was unconditional

Comment: I believe it is addressed in the paper (C.4). Back in the day, "unconditional" was called "absolute".

Comment: @DavidMitra Unconditional means that you may reorder the terms of the series. Absolute means that the series of norms of the terms is convergent.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The paper uses "absolute" to mean "unconditional".  It is even defined as such in the paper.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks. I have found a free access to this paper from 1958 [here](https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/1388044)

Comment: @DavidMitra - Thank you. I didn't know that "absolute" used to mean "unconditional." In this case (C.4) from Bessaga and Pełczyński's article, it is, clearly, the answer to my question.